# Separate login forms for types of users

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

I'm feeling a bit stuck here and I'm not sure which way to proceed. I'm using the Doctrine ORM in which I have a `User` entity and a `Group` entity.

The `User` entity has a 'belongs to' field which defines whether the users are in the medics group, patients group or firms group. There are two pages to login on the site : let's call them page1 an page2. I'd like to have everyone (patients, medics and firms) be able to log in on page1, but only medics and firms in page2.

To restrict pacients from logging from the page2 form,
I tried creating a new login controller and overriding the other `loginAction()` method and the `checkAction()` method but the problem seems to be that I can't capture the form elements. I also tried looking into creating a new entry into the firewall but I don't see how that is of any help since I don't need to restrict a particular set of pages to one class since that is already done in controllers.

Do I need to write a custom validator to accomplish this? If so, how can I check which type of user I have?

Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, maybe usefull:

1. Define some role in `User` *Entity*
2. Then in *`app/config/security.yml`*:

   ```
   security:

       role_hierarchy:
           ROLE_ADMIN:         [ROLE_FIRMS,ROLE_MEDICS] //define in User Entity
   ```

   `access_control:`

   ```
       - { path: ^/someRoute/page$,     roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
   ```
3. other things depend to authorization system that used.

This is useful bundle for fully control User: [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)